# Getting started developing JSDT/wst.jsdt?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830027/eclipse-outline-view-visible-javascript-categories-in-eclipse) I [spotted a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=312841) in the Eclipse wst.jsdt.  If I want to fix this myself, what are the knowledge dependencies for doing so?

My guess would be:

- Know how to use CVS
- Know how to use Bugzilla
- Know how to develop core libraries in Eclipse
- Know how to develop plugins in Eclipse
- Know how to develop for the wst.jsdt project

I've never done the latter three, so I was just wondering if anybody could point me in the right direction.

I already [looked at a document](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JSDTDevelopment) for developing in JSDT, but I'm still a little uncertain about what I need to look for to develop for Eclipse, since it comes in various flavors/distros (i.e. WDT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the RCP edition (see **[Eclipse packages](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/compare.php)**), to which you add the WTP module.

As for the [participation](http://eclipseblog.ostroukhovs.com/2009/12/11/participate-in-community-they-said/), you have here some advices on [how to contribute to Eclipse projects](http://blog.hantsuki.org/2008/03/07/how-to-contribute-to-eclipse-projects/), but on this topic, the **[official page is now here](http://eclipse.org/contribute/)**.